# Automatic SNI resolution between CDN and origins is not currently supported for Azure CDN from Verizon

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

When activating SNI, we get 502 from azure CDN when using Azure Standard Verizon

Answer (score 0):

SNI is not enabled by default but can be applied to the Verizon CDN endpoint manually by raising a support ticket through the Azure portal. HTH